# Why does agg function take Column followed by Seq(Column), but not directly Seq(Column)

Tags: apache-spark

According to documentation in Spark, one of the agg method definitions is:

```
Dataset<Row>    agg(Column expr, scala.collection.Seq<Column> exprs)
```

Why is the 1st argument "Column expr" compulsory? Why not:

```
Dataset<Row>    agg(scala.collection.Seq<Column> exprs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by @jaceklaskowski this could to avoid runtime errors where there are no aggregations in the Seq exprs